# How can I print Mutt Mail User Agent Inbox list in a text file?

Tags: linux, email, mutt

How can I print Mutt Mail User Agent Inbox list in a text file?

That's my problem:

I need to print the Inbox files list, which have are with the following set:

`set index_format="%4C %Z %{%d/%m/%y %H:%M} %s"`

That way I need to print them in a text file, with the following example content:

`10 N F 08/07/19 08:53 Attention: alarm(14286247:motion detection)
  11 N F 08/07/19 08:53 Attention: alarm(14033396:motion detection)
  12 N F 08/07/19 08:53 Attention: alarm(12063427:motion detection)
  13 N F 08/07/19 08:52 Attention: alarm(14033396:motion detection)
  14 N F 08/07/19 08:51 Attention: alarm(14033396:motion detection)
  15 N F 08/07/19 08:51 Attention: alarm(14286247:motion detection)
  16 N F 08/07/19 08:51 Attention: alarm(13809971:motion detection)
  17 N F 08/07/19 08:49 Attention: alarm(14286247:motion detection)
  18 N F 08/07/19 08:49 Attention: alarm(14033396:motion detection)
  19 N F 08/07/19 08:48 Attention: alarm(14286247:motion detection)
  20 N F 08/07/19 08:48 Attention: alarm(14033396:motion detection)
  21 N F 08/07/19 08:48 Attention: alarm(12063427:motion detection)
  22 N F 08/07/19 08:46 Attention: alarm(14033396:motion detection)
  23 N F 08/07/19 08:47 Attention: alarm(13809971:motion detection)
  24 N F 08/07/19 08:45 Attention: alarm(12063427:motion detection)
  25 N F 08/07/19 08:45 Attention: alarm(14033396:motion detection)
  26 N F 08/07/19 08:46 Attention: alarm(13809971:motion detection)
  27 N F 08/07/19 08:44 Attention: alarm(14286247:motion detection)
  28 N F 08/07/19 08:40 Attention: alarm(12063427:motion detection)
  29 N F 08/07/19 08:39 Attention: alarm(14033396:motion detection)
  30 N F 08/07/19 08:38 Attention: alarm(14033396:motion detection)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying printing the Mutt Mail User Agent inbox, you should seek the mail files itself, they sometimes contains the timestamps too.

There is the NeoMutt documentations, which may help you:

https://neomutt.org/dev/documentation